# Why when I write with Rcpp I do not need to include some libraries which I should include writing in plain C++?

Tags: c++, r, include, rcpp

I was running the following chunk of code using Rcpp

```
src <- '
Rcpp::NumericVector vec(vx);
double p = Rcpp::as<double>(dd);
double sum = 0.0;
for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
sum += pow(vec[i], p);
}
return Rcpp::wrap(sum);
'

fun <- cxxfunction(signature(vx="numeric", dd="numeric"),
src, plugin="Rcpp")

fun(1:4,2)
```

And I got the result 30 (which is correct). If I run the function pow(x,y) in plain C++ I need to add the

```
#include <math>
```

Why I don't need to do so writing under Rcpp?

Comment: I'm guessing that Rcpp already includes some headers by default.

Comment: How can I check which libraries are already included?

Comment: Rcpp provides significant access to many R functions -- many of which are vector-friendly functions -- as direct calls from Rcpp functions. `pow` is one of them. You can see several examples in [Rcpp-sugar](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-sugar.pdf), which should be included in your Rcpp package. I'm guessing it's possible to override this and use the native lower-level `pow`, but off the top of my head I can't think of it.

Comment: To see which external C++ libraries are included (along with a few others), do something like this: `dir <- system.file("include", package="Rcpp"); x <- dir(dir, recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE, all.files=TRUE); xx <- unname(unique(unlist(sapply(x, function(X) grep("^#include", readLines(X), value=TRUE))))); grep("Rcpp", xx, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pow` function is part of Rcpp Sugar when you use it on an R object.  I don't think every function from the math library has been converted so don't expect every function to work on R objects.  You can see the vignette [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-sugar.pdf) detailing a few of the functions implemented.

Now, if you are wondering instead why you don't need the math library when using `pow` on a normal C++ object such as this very simple example:

```
src <- '
double t = 2;
double o = pow(t, 2);
return wrap(o);
'

fun <- cxxfunction(signature(),
                   src, plugin="Rcpp")
fun()
[1] 4
```

This is because Rcpp is indeed importing headers by default as you suspect.  The list of headers is shown in the source code.  The file of interest to you is likely [this](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/functions.h) where you will see that the cmath library is included.  Most of the base C++ headers seem to be located [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/RcppCommon.h).

That said, you may find it tedious to go through the source code and the call suggested by Josh is truly something special to get a quick look at the libraries but you should also be aware of where the information actually comes from instead of the magic of a single call, IMHO.

Comment: Nice anser.  Even more concise via `cppFunction("double fun(double x, double p=2) { return std::pow(x, p); }")`.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question narrowly:

- because your `#include <Rcpp.h>` leads to other headers being included for you

as `Rcpp.h` includes them for your (and nice trick by Josh to grep for which; I'd still do that at the command-line).  You use the older `cxxfunction()` from package [inline](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=inline), it adds the `include`  for `Rcpp.h` for you.  Rcpp Attributes is even easier (see my comment to CDterman's answer), it also adds required headers for you.

Also note that `pow()` is defined both as a scalar function (ie `double` in, `double` out) and, as CDeterman said, in Rcpp sugar (where it works for Rcpp objects in a *vectorised* manner).  You can control which you use by explicit namespace use: ie `std::pow()` would get the former.